# Bitnami redirects localhost to another ip

Tags: apache, redirect, forwarding, bitnami

I just installed the bitnami stack.
When going to 127.0.0.1 it works fine on the root page but when trying to access one of my applications I got a redirect somehow to an IP which does not exist.

What do I need to configure in order to prevent the bitnamit apache switching to another ip?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Bitnami developer here.

Note that some apps require the domain/ip configuration. Probably you have to reconfigure it to not redirect to localhost. The IP/domain is required during the installation process. You can reinstall it or check the specific Bitnami app wiki to know how to configure it.

I hope it helps,

Comment: thanks a lot for coming back to this. I ' ll check it tomorrow :)